# New Lenovo laptop what should I do?

Tags: thinkpad

So we all know Lenovo have been on the limelight over the past year with their questionable added software / data selling but I still love the ThinkPad line.

If I was to buy a brand new ThinkPad / any Lenovo product should I get a new HDD just-in-case is there anything else I can do vendor agnostic to make sure that the new hardware hasn't got any hidden surprises?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Lets move this to Hardware recommendations.

Comment: Lets not. Its not on topic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lenovo's Think-branded laptops do not have, and never have had, [LSE rubbish](http://news.lenovo.com/article_display.cfm?article_id=2013) installed or present in BIOS firmware. Similarly, the Think-branded laptops do not have, and never have had, [Superfish rubbish](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/superfish) installed.

Generally Lenovo play it very safe with their business/enterprise line of products. If you go with a ThinkPad today, you're all good.

Now you may not *like* Lenovo's behavior, and perhaps for this reason you might not want to support them by buying their products. That's fair enough.

But me personally, I take a more pragmatic approach. Google, Apple, and Microsoft have been *far* more invasive in recent years. At least Lenovo un-did the above two "mistakes". We should be more concerned about the OS' and software we're running (which is why I prefer Linux these days). IMHO Lenovo still make the best business/enterprise laptops you can get. They are solid and reliable, and the keyboards are a pleasure to type on. Linux support is also excellent, if that's your thing.

> should I get a new HDD

That would be a waste of your time and money. Just wipe the HDD it comes with. On new PCs I boot up a Linux Mint Live ISO (CD or USB Key), launch GParted, and create a new blank partition table. Done. Then you can install what you want. Linux, Windows, whatever, without any of Lenovo's pre-installed stuff getting in your way.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I didn't know the Think line wasn't part of the LSE or Superfish stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't.

> Six months after apologising to users for pre-installing security-busting malware Superfish on its consumer laptops, Chinese PC manufacturer Lenovo has again had to remove another pre-installed component from its laptops over security fears.
>
> But this time, the problem software, called the “Lenovo Service Engine (LSE)”, is built into the firmware of the laptops themselves, in a low-level operating system called the BIOS, invisible even to Windows.

They included malware in the BIOS. They've released a removal tool but there's no way anyone can have any faith that there aren't more holes in their firmware that we don't know about. The public have caught them twice in 6 months, its not unreasonable to think there are more inclusions we've yet to discover.

Comment: Such a shame when the ThinkPad line is a great piece of hardware

Answer (score 0):

The LSE is built into bios and wont go away with change/format of HDD. It uses a method (BootKit) which was originally designed to inject tacking software to new installs so that the laptop can be tracked by organisation even if windows was reinstalled.
I too like the thinkpad line but with both lenovo phones being left out and such security intrusions, i think it is better for all to stay away from lenovo for near future.

If you are running linux, LSE shouldnt affect you as it is a windows only software. I am not 100% sure on this though.

Comment: oh really, that is interesting as I was going to run linux...